# iOS - New Firebase Crashlytics (4.0.0-beta.5) - dSYM upload fails

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, crashlytics, dsym

error: Could not complete submission of dSYM at /Users/apple/Downloads/appDsyms/f744f519-c397-3c57-b7e7-1adc45ac4936.dSYM: Error Domain=com.google.firebase.crashlytics.FIRCLSCompoundOperation.error Code=4294967293 "(null)" UserInfo={com.google.firebase.crashlytics.FIRCLSCompoundOperation.error.user-info-key.underlying-errors=(

Comment: This is the command I  used /Users/apple/Documents/Abhishek/iOS_Workspace/iOSProjects/ios_wp2/Pods/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols -gsp /Users/apple/Documents/Abhishek/iOS_Workspace/iOSProjects/ios_wp2/Firebase/utkarsh/GoogleService-Info.plist -p ios /Users/apple/Downloads/appDsyms/

Comment: Related issues at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues?q=is%3Aissue+label%3A%22api%3A+crashlytics%22+

Comment: I faced this issue when open multiple copy of same project. I Closed second copy, then removed derived data, clean the project using (command + shift + K ) and then quit and open project. After that working. I repeat same process 2-3 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try copy and pasting the exact scripts written in [these instructions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-sdk?platform=ios#update-code), i.e. ${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/run
/path/to/pods/directory/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (Flutter), FIREBASE_APP_ID was wrong.

Before (Run Script):

```
# Source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports?platform=flutter#run-script-exists

FIREBASE_APP_ID="1:1111111111:ios:1111111111111111111111"
if [ "${ENV}" == "dev" ]; then 
FIREBASE_APP_ID="1:2222222222:ios:2222222222222222222222"
elif [ "${ENV}" == "stg" ]; then
FIREBASE_APP_ID="1:3333333333:ios:3333333333333333333333"
fi

$PODS_ROOT/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols --build-phase --validate -ai FIREBASE_APP_ID -- $DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH/Runner.app.dSYM

$PODS_ROOT/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols --build-phase -ai FIREBASE_APP_ID -- $DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH/Runner.app.dSYM
```

After (Run Script):

```
# Source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports?platform=flutter#run-script-exists

FIREBASE_APP_ID="1:1111111111:ios:1111111111111111111111"
if [ "${ENV}" == "dev" ]; then 
FIREBASE_APP_ID="1:2222222222:ios:2222222222222222222222"
elif [ "${ENV}" == "stg" ]; then
FIREBASE_APP_ID="1:3333333333:ios:3333333333333333333333"
fi

# ↓ FIREBASE_APP_ID -> $FIREBASE_APP_ID
$PODS_ROOT/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols --build-phase --validate -ai $FIREBASE_APP_ID -- $DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH/Runner.app.dSYM

# ↓ FIREBASE_APP_ID -> $FIREBASE_APP_ID
$PODS_ROOT/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols --build-phase -ai $FIREBASE_APP_ID -- $DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH/Runner.app.dSYM
```